# Printing and removing parts of a string

Tags: python, string, variables, indexing

I am working on a program that changes the user's inputted word into Pig Latin.

```py
def main():
    word = input('Please enter a word ')
    if word[0] == "A" or "E" or "I" or "O" or "U":
        print(word + "HAY")
    else:
        print(word + word[0] + "HAY")
      
main()
```

I have a certain set of rules to follow: if the user's inputted word has a, e, i, o,or u as its starting index, the program prints the word with `HAY` printed at the end of it. If the word has any other letter at the beginning, the program is supposed to take the first letter of the word and place it at the front of `HAY`.

That's where my issue is. I can't quite figure out what I am supposed to type in order to have the program remove that first index and place it just behind where `HAY` prints.

Comment: Try `print(word[1:] + word[0] + "HAY")` to skip the first letter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Let me quickly elaborate on why your initial if statement doesn't work: `or` in Python compares boolean values, so if you wanted to do the statement your way you would have to do `if word[0] == "A" or word[0] == "E" or`...etc. You can't just do `"A" or "E"` because `or` doesn't work with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me note that your initial if statement is flawed and always executes the if and never the else. So I changed it. I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
def main():
    word = input('Please enter a word ')
    if word[0] in "AEIOU":
        print(word + "hay")
    else:
        print(word[1].upper() + word[2:] + word[0].lower() + "ay")

main()
```

This uses string slicing, where string[a:b] goes from string[a] up to but not including string[b], and when I leave out b it just goes to the end of the word.